VideoTexture on a single face of model
I'm importing the very first model I made in Blender 4.2, which consists of a computer and two monitors, into my three.js scene.
I have a VideoTexture map set up on the "computer screen" that I got from the model by traversing the scene. My problem is the video texture spans across the whole mesh.
Here's that code:
const monitorScreenOne = document.getElementById( 'monitor-1-video' );
const textureTwo = new THREE.VideoTexture( monitorScreenOne );

// MODEL
const loader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager)
loader.load('resources/script/lol/test.gltf', (gltf) => {
    gltf.scene.traverse(function(node) {
        if(node.name == 'screen-monitor-display'){
            node.position.x = 10
            node.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: textureTwo,
            })

            monitorScreenOne.load()
            monitorScreenOne.setAttribute('playsinline', true)
        }
    })
    scene.add(gltf.scene)
})

And here is its output:
computer screne with working video texture. It's sideways, but I'll fix that later.
Now, when I add some extra materials to be applied to each face (which is what I got from this stackoverflow link), using this code:
// MODEL
const loader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager)
loader.load('resources/script/lol/test.gltf', (gltf) => {
    gltf.scene.traverse(function(node) {
        if(node.name == 'screen-monitor-display'){
            node.position.x = 10
            node.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: textureTwo,
            })
            node.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
            node.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
            node.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
            node.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
            node.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()

            monitorScreenOne.load()
            monitorScreenOne.setAttribute('playsinline', true)
        }
    })
    scene.add(gltf.scene)
})

And here is it's output: computer scene with non-working video texture. As you can see in the image, every face is a normal material.
I'm obviously handling this the wrong way. How could I get the video texture on a single face on the screen object in the scene while making every other face of the object a different material?

In the example you link, assigning an array of materials to mesh.material, it's assumed that the geometry of that Mesh has been initialized with multiple geometry groups. For example, THREE.BoxGeometry comes with 6 geometry groups by default, one for each of the box's sides, typically having two triangles per group. Materials cannot be assigned to individual triangles – only to entire meshes, or to particular geometry groups.
Meshes loaded from a glTF model will not have geometry groups in three.js, and unless you happen to know that the part of the screen you want to use is (for example) triangles 35–75 in the "screen-monitor-display" mesh, it's going to be difficult to programmatically create those groups.
In most cases, it is much easier to open the glTF model in Blender, separate the parts you want to modify into a different mesh with a different name, and then look for a mesh with that name in three.js.

I see what you're saying, that makes alot of sense. Thanks for the clarification!
